# Play sound in Background on Timer Set

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my app I want to play sounds after setting the timer from my Timer Page where I put the Time after which selected sound should be played. I want to play the selected sound even if my application is closed. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using Alarm or Remdiner classes

How to: Create Alarms and Reminders for Windows Phone
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965(v=vs.92)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm(v=VS.92).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.schedulednotification(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Alarms can have a sound set to them, but there is no way to customize that dialog to not show and not need snooze or dismiss functionality.So how can I achieve that?

Comment: that is true.. there is not way to customise the dialog / buttons shown. WPDev is restrictive in what you can and cannot do. In foreground you can write your own form and rely on system alarm if app loses focus ?